# combining 2 object by id and save mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I start working on my own project and I have a problem.
I got an object called Authority : ["Authoritiy" schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCwbB.png)

now I have another object called "Tohnit". ["Tohnit" schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCjIt.png)

The problem that I have, I want to select an Authority from DB, then I want to combine between the Authority and Tohnit and save it on the save Authority I was selected.

I prepare a logic if it will help to understand.
[some logic of what I try to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W97DC.png)

Comment: The code you display doesn't do what you wish ? It saves the new Tohnit inside the Authoritie and created it in its collection. Could you rephrase your question ?

Comment: exactly what I thought, but the object that you see authorities.Tohnit.push() is not an array so you can't push because I created above a mongoose schema reference. 
but now that I explain this to you, I think I just understood my problem!

p.s. I try to save it by reference and not by value.